# Can I share my Hangout App with other users?

Tags: google-hangouts

I have written a Hangout App to send the youtube live id of my HoA to my server.  Currently the app loads only if i start the HoA with my G+ account ( the one I used to create the Application ). If I make the app public, will all  users be able to load my app ?

Note :  Below is the code I use to start the HoA
         
          https://talkgadget.google.com/hangouts/_" method = "GET">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I share my Hangout App with other users?
Yes

If I make the app public, will all users be able to load my app ?
Yes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your app is made public ever google user can access your hangout app.

But to do this you need to click on this link (https://console.developers.google.com/project). then go to you project--> APIs --> original console --> check make your app public there you need to follow the remaining step to make your app public.